# What's the equivalent of Ext.Window in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to write a simple Sencha Touch mobile application.

in ExtJs there is a Ext.Window class, but I couldn't find it in Sencha Touch.

What should I use in Sencha Touch to do the same job of ExtJs Ext.Window.

Comment: can you elaborate what do you want to accomplish on using Ext.window for touch apps?

Answer (score 3):

Concept of window is obsolete on the touch devices. For this reason, Sencha Touch doesn't have any window component. Agree maybe sometimes you need it but you always can refine your design and find a better solution.

If you really need something like window, I would try something similar to Ext.MessageBox: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/source/MessageBox.html#Ext-MessageBox